# R changes all values in a matrix when adding a column

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say I have a matrix

```
t = matrix( 
 c(7:12), 
 nrow=3, 
ncol=2)
```

Now I'm going to add a column called "Time" where the text value for all rows is implied (let's say "text")

```
t = cbind (t, Time = "text")
```

Now if I check the matrix, I see that all numerical values are also transformed into the text ones:

```
              Time  
[1,] "7" "10" "text"
[2,] "8" "11" "text"
[3,] "9" "12" "text"
```

Accordingly, all functions like colMeans or colSums don't work anymore...
What the problem might be? I tried to transform the matrix to a dataframe (as.data.frame), but it doesn't help. My final goal is to apply some math functions and then to save this matrix as a XLS table with both numerical and text data and all variables named like this:

```
     1   2    Time  
[1,] 7   10   text
[2,] 8   11   text
[3,] 9   12   text
```

Is there any simple solution for that?

Comment: use a dataframe! `dft <- as.data.frame(matrix(7:12, 3)); dft$Time <- "text"`

Comment: Use a `data.frame` rather than a `matrix`. You will be able to keep different types in the same "table".

Comment: The storage mode for all the elements of a matrix can either be numeric or character but not both. on the other hand, since the storage mode of a data frame is a list, we know that we can have elements of various classes within a list. You thus need to work with a data frame rather than a matrix.